# page redirect after time interval

Tags: redirect, time, intervals

Friend clicks button. Link #1 pops up in new window. After 10 seconds of viewing link #1 it redirects to Link #2 in the same window. It views Link #2 for 10 seconds then redirects to Link #3, repeat. How can i go about doing this...?

I'm having a terrible time figuring this out.

Comment: What does this have to do with java? I am going to remove the java tag now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the **head** section of your Link#1 page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://address-ofLinnk#2-page">
```

After 10 seconds it will forward to the url you specify.